# Reset all observers in Shiny

Tags: shiny

I have a shiny application that performs the following

- observers a slider
- show a modal after 1 minute
- record the slider value
- remove the modal after 10 seconds
- reset the slider

  ** repeat 10 times

This is making my reactivity chain grow, along with CPU usage and latency.
Is there a way to ''refresh'' or ''reset'' all of the observers in shiny?
Currently, I manually re-validate observers with `MyreactiveValue$Trigger <<- FALSE`

Including `shinyjs::flushReact` doees the opposite of what I want.

Comment: You can use `observeEvent(..., once = TRUE)` to make sure your observers get "destroyed" after they are triggered for the first time.

Comment: I can't actually destroy them because I need to reuse them again.